Are superinsulators perfect dielectrics?
In Wikipedia its stated: "The phenomenon of superinsulation can be regarded as an exact dual to superconductivity."
I understand that superinsulators are terrible conductors. But its not clear to me if they are perfect dielectrics.
So I want to ask, are they perfect dielectrics? Do they polarize to completely expel sufficiently weak electric fields in a way similar to how superconductors completely expel sufficiently weak magnetic fields form their interior? And so naturally one can ask is there basically an electric Meissner effect caused by this?
In a sense this is the first question I should have asked before attempting to ask this.

Yes. Just as superconductors truly are perfect conductors, superinsulators truly are perfect dielectrics. In the bulk, they have zero permittivity. As such, this gives rise to the complete expulsion of electric fields from the material - as you predicted, this is called the electric Meissner effect.
See Direct probe of the interior of an electric pion in a Cooper pair superinsulator, section "A theory of the electric Meissner state" for a more detailed introduction.

Thanks for the answer! Btw your profile url: https://riscj.dev/ is a dead link atm
